# Exporting GeoPackage layer to GeoJSON changes CRS from WGS 84 EPSG:4326 to OGC:CRS84

Tags: qgis, geojson, wgs84, epsg, ogc

I'm attempting to convert a polygon layer from GeoPackage format to GeoJSON in QGIS 3.10.1. The original layer has a coordinate reference system of WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) which is what I need. Yet the resulting GeoJSON output has a coordinate reference system of OGC:CRS84 which is causing invalid GeoJSON errors when attempting to import it into various web applications.

i.e. GeoJSONLint, Right Hand Rule GeoJSON Fixer, etc. I keep getting the "Line 1: old-style crs member is not recommended, this object is equivalent to the default and should be removed" error.

How can I get the resulting GeoJSON file to stop converting the CRS and keep WGS 84 (EPSG:4326). Or is this the intended behavior of QGIS upon export to GeoJSON and I'm thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Try if you can add an  extra layer creation option `RFC7946=YES` https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html. OGC:CRS84 does not make any real difference to EPSG:4326 when you deal with GeoJSON but they mean the same: coordinates are in WGS84 degrees the order of coordinates is longitude-latitude.

Answer (score 5):

> Or is this the intended behavior of QGIS upon export to GeoJSON and I'm thinking about this wrong?

I don't know what the intended behaviour of QGIS is, but if the intention is to write GeoJSON according its specification (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) or just RFC7946 for short.  Then yes.

Section 4 of RFC7946 tells us that

> The coordinate reference system for all GeoJSON coordinates is a
> geographic coordinate reference system, using the World Geodetic
> System 1984 (WGS 84) [WGS84] datum, with longitude and latitude units
> of decimal degrees.  This is equivalent to the coordinate reference
> system identified by the Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) URN
> urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84.

Note the datum `World Geodetic System 1984` (alias WGS 84) is defined by [EPSG::6326](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?gml=urn:ogc:def:datum:EPSG::6326)

`urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84` is **NOT the same** as `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326`  They share the same datum, but the axis order is different, OGC::CRS84 is long/lat and EPSG::4326 is lat/long.

There is no 'crs' member in GeoJSON (GeoJSON is RFC7946), because the CRS is **ALWAYS** urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84 or at least (for pedants) the 2D CRS is always urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84.

*You can by 'arrangement' (say in an internal application) use a different CRS, but if you're exchanging GeoJSON or publishing GeoJSON, the expectation will be that it's urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84*

> GeoJSONLint, Right Hand Rule GeoJSON Fixer, etc. I keep getting the "Line 1: old-style crs member is not recommended, this object is equivalent to the default and should be removed" error.

So the warning is correct here if you have a crs member and the crs is stated as being OGC::CRS84.

Prior to the specification, in the draft (aka GeoJSON 2008), there was a crs member and other CRS were allowed.

Contrary to the advice of @user30184 you don't want to use the option `RFC7946=YES` if you want a crs member and EPSG:4326 as the CRS; you want `RFC7946=NO`, though it should be the default for GDAL/OGR.

> RFC7946=YES/NO. (OGR >= 2.2) Whether to use RFC 7946 standard. Otherwise GeoJSON 2008 initial version will be used. Default is NO (thus GeoJSON 2008).

Comment: Great explanation! I think that GDAL will not save the `EPSG::4326` crs member from a QGIS _EPSG:4326_ layer, because the _x/y_ axis order assumption by QGIS.(Also, I think that OP doesn't want the `EPSG::4326` crs member, and just want the GoeJSON without crs member, although that was not their question.)